# Convert zip file to gzip and write to hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, gzip

I have a zip file which I want to convert to gzip and write it back to the filesystem. How can I do this?

I already have this code to compress a file to gzip:

```
private static void compressGzipFile(String file, String gzipFile) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(gzipFile);
        GZIPOutputStream gzipOS = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        while ((len=fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            gzipOS.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        // Close resources
        gzipOS.close();
        fos.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I need code to convert the zip file into a gzip file.

Comment: You can't convert a zip file to a gzip file, because zip-files can contain files, while gzip doesn't. Do you want to gzip the zip file instead (which I doubt will be effective).

Answer (score -1):

Why not just pipe a [`ZipInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) directly into a [`GZIPOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html)?

```
private static void convertZipToGzip(String zipFile, String gzipFile) {
    try (ZipInputStream zipIS = new ZipInputStream(file),
         GZIPOutputStream gzipOS = new GZIPOutputStream(gzipFile)) {
        zipIS.transferTo(gzipOS);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This solution takes advantage of Java 9’s incredibly useful [`InputStream#transferTo(OutputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo-java.io.OutputStream-). If you’re not yet using Java 9, you’ll need to manually copy the bytes from one stream to the other, or use Apache Commons IOUtils’ [`IOUtils.copy(InputStream, OutputStream)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)).

Comment: the code in the answer take the zip file and compress it to gzip, I looking for code the take the zip content and compress it go gzip